# Regex help to match just the url in log

Tags: regex

I have 1000s of log lines and what I want to do is capture just the url so can assign it to a variable in python then use urlparse to manipulate it. 
Here is 1 log line:

```
2015-04-01 01:01:10 0 192.0.0.1 17204100 192.0.0.1 80 words/123 123 WORD http://something-something.domain.com/folder1/folder2/folder/123432523324325_word_word_file.zipuuid=1234533&something=%205920&word=all&_123 - 3 123 "-" "helloworld/1" 1234 "words"; 127.0.0.1, 192.0.0.1; 3"
```

What I want to capture is just:
http://something-something.domain.com/folder1/folder2/folder/123432523324325_word_word_file.zipuuid=1234533&something=%205920&word=all&_123

My regex doesn’t seem to stop at the space:

```
(http://.*)[^\s]
```

My thought is that I would be able to capture anything that had http:// all the way up to the space \s  but for some reason in reggy it seems to capture everything after http://

Thanks!

Comment: Where do you want to capture this?  A command line perhaps?  What about something like `egrep -o 'https?://[^[:space:]]+' logfile.log` ?

Comment: I'm using python to read in the log file. Using reggex to grab just the address then urlparse to break it up. At least thats the plan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> capture anything that had http:// all the way up to the space \s

```
https?://\S+
```

Use `\S` for non space characters.